# How to remove additional consoles in Datagrip (2017.3.1)

Tags: datagrip

I have created a few additional consoles for my "Dev" database (see green arrows) but would like to clean them up to leave just the original one (see blue arrow).

[image]

This would appear to be a simple thing to want to do but it seems to be one of the hardest things to do and unfortunately I cannot work it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Immediately after posting this I found the solution which is to (if using a mac) press `cmd 2` which opens up the "Files" view. You can then view the database consoles and delete the ones required.

[image]